# Reading custom JS Files in rails 4.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4.1 project I have the following code:

```
{
    <% = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true%> 
}
```

which I load all my js files with extention. My question is if there is another way to load the .js files that are only of resources necessary for a given form ??????

Answer (score 0):

Just add another comma and include the name of the .js file. So if you wanted a special javascript file for your form validations called form.js on a particular view you would put the following code...

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "form" %>
```

If you wanted multiple javascript files for 1 view it would look like this

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "form", "script_2", "script_3" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, put this on your page:

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

and put myscript.js in the `public/` directory.